# Assigning Usernames to Socket.io ID's

Tags: javascript, socket.io

I am trying to take the username sent from the client and attach it to their socket ID so that it can be used later in the code. I am currently trying to use an array to store this data. On disconnect I want it to remove the player from the array. This is not working. I feel like I incorrectly created and assigned values to my array.

**Here is my server side code (index.js)**

```
var express = require('express');
var socket = require('socket.io');
var people = [];

var app = express();
var server = app.listen(5000, '0.0.0.0', function(){
    console.log("connected to port 5000")
});

app.use(express.static('public'));

var io = socket(server);

numUsers = 0;


io.on('connection', function(socket){
    console.log('socket connection -', socket.id)

    socket.on('nname', function(data){
        ++numUsers;
        io.emit('nname', data);
        console.log('new player registered -', data.nickname, numUsers)
        people[socket.id] = data.nickname;
        console.log(people)
    });
    socket.on('disconnect', function(){
        people.splice(socket.id,1);
        console.log('Disconnection', people);
    })
});
```

**Here is my client side code (answers.js)**

```
var socket = io.connect('localhost:5000');

var nickname = document.getElementById('nickname'),
    btn = document.getElementById('submitnickname');

btn.addEventListener('click', function(){
    socket.emit('nname', {
        nickname: nickname.value
    });
    document.getElementById('popup').style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById('waiting').style.display = "block"
});
```

This is the console output I get when a new player is registered.
[image: console output on player username assignment]
This is the console output I get when a player disconnects
[image: console output on player disconnect]
As you can see the socket ID and username are still in the array. What am I doing wrong? Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: is there any specific reason that you are creating your people array this way instead of maybe array of objects of just an object of id, username mapping?

Comment: Since you're indexing by a string id, don't use an array, use an object. You can't splice a key-value pair from an object.

Answer (score 1):

Replace the `people.splice(socket.id,1);` line with:

```
delete people[socket.id];
```

This has something to do with [enumerable properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Enumerability_and_ownership_of_properties)

Comment: This has nothing to do with enumerable properties. OP is using an array like an object.

Comment: I can't really tell. The reason I suspect it has something to do with enumerables is that splice only works with integer indexes, but the delete solution works. Can you explain a little better your point.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to create a seperate array. You can create a new property on socket object like this.

```
socket.username = "myusername";
```

Comment: If I were to do it this way is there a way for me to list all the users and their usernames?

Comment: @KevinLong I dont know for sure and I cant test right now as I am away from my computer. If there isn't a way to iterate through sockets, you can use array for listing usernames. But I still suggest to use  the method I wrote above together with array, because looking up for username by id in an array would be very ineffective in my opinion.

Comment: I think you mean `socket.data.username`. `socket.username` won't be shared in a multi-server setup as far as I can see [reading the manual](https://socket.io/docs/v4/server-api).